# Change MAC address ubuntu MATE 16.04.1

Tags: networking

I have an Ubuntu Mate 16.04.1 installed on a pen drive and I would like to use a different MAC address when I boot this system.

To be more specific I'd like to use always the same address, and to change that before connecting to the network.

I read a lot of guide but none of them works for me. I tried to use macchanger but when I connect to the network my MAC turn back to the original one.

If someone can help I will really appreciate.
Thank you